# Can I tell IntelliJ (10.5) not to warn about not passing an optional javascript method argument?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, code-analysis

```
function foo(a, opt_b) {
  opt_b = opt_b || 1;
  ...
}

foo(1);  // IntelliJ will yell at me, saying "Invalid number of parameters, expected 2"
```

Is there a way to document `foo()` such that IntelliJ won't yell at me?

Comment: Besides switching to CoffeeScript, that is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using JavaDoc-style comments for JavaScript, you can declare a parameter as optional with brackets [] around it:

```
/**
 * My function
 * @param [optionalParam] An optional parameter
 */
myFunction: function(optionalParam) {
    //...
},
```

Comment: Nice solution, though if you're using Google's closure compiler then you may not want to use this notation since it is incompatible, IIRC.

Answer (score 7):

"JavaScript > General > Signature Mismatch Problem" is the inspection setting that will disable the incorrect-number-of-parameters warning for you.  Unfortunately, it affects more than just parameter count.  According to the description inside IntelliJ IDEA, it "Checks JavaScript called function parameters, return values, assigned expressions to be of correct type.  The validation works in JavaScript, html or jsp files."

[image: Turn off JavaScript parameter count warnings (and all type warnings as well)]

Answer (score 2):

According to http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html there are two ways to use comments to declare a parameter as optional:

```
/**
 * @param {string} [somebody] - Somebody's name.
 */
function sayHello(somebody) {
    if (!somebody) {
        somebody = 'John Doe';
    }
    alert('Hello ' + somebody);
}
```

and

```
/**
 * @param {string=} somebody - Somebody's name.
 */
function sayHello(somebody) {
    if (!somebody) {
        somebody = 'John Doe';
    }
    alert('Hello ' + somebody);
}
```

Both ways worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the settings via ***inspections*** option for JS:

[image]

Comment: function with too many parameters - isn't this inspection about a function that has a lot of parameters `f(a,b,c,d,e)`, and not about calling a function and not passing optional args? This setting is off, so it must not be it. I was thinking of some way to document an optional param.